# dplyr mutate column headings - R studio

Tags: r, dplyr

While executing below calculation in R the column heading is returned as the code. How to assign a specific column heading?

```
library (dplyr)
it_cs7_fc <- it_cs7 %>%
  mutate((difference_1 = CS7_end - CS7_start))
```

Output:

```
(difference_1 = CS7_end - CS7_start)              : num  0.0403 0 0.0495 0.2478 0.1796 ...
```

How to change the column heading? Tried rename but of no help

```
it_cs7_fc <- it_cs7 %>%
mutate((difference_1 = CS7_end - CS7_start)%>%
rename(difference_1 = CS7_diff))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the extra parentheses. `mutate()` expects a formula like `colname = terms_that_create_values` but when you put an extra set of parentheses around it, the full formula will be used as the new column name.

Comment: The extra parens (as @JonSpring said) are the problem, perhaps just a typo (or a misunderstanding). In many/most places, an extra set of parens do no harm (mostly where algebraic grouping is reinforced), but not here. `mutate(quux = 1)` calls mutate with one argument `1` named `quux`; `mutate((quux = 1))` calls mutate with one argument `(quux = 1)` with no name. In dplyr and almost all other places, that is a very different thing.

Comment: @Jon Spring and r2evans - thanks, removing the extra parentheses did the magic.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many parentheses.

In many (most?) places in R, an extra set of parentheses does no harm, often just reinforcing algebraic grouping (e.g., `(1+1)` or `(((1+1)+2))`). However, within function calls they can change how arguments are interpreted.

As an example, see this function:

```r
fun <- function(...) {
  dots <- list(...)
  cat(paste("len(Args) :", length(dots)), "\n")
  cat(paste("len(Names):", length(names(dots)), "\n"))
  cat(paste("Names     :", toString(names(dots)), "\n"))
}
```

Calling it the "normal" way works fine:

```r
fun(quux = 1+2)
# len(Args) : 1 
# len(Names): 1 
# Names     : quux
```

But if we surround the arguments with an extra set of parens, we see that while there is still an argument passed, it is not named. **Before you do that**, look quickly to see if the object `quux` exists in your local environment. (If it does, choose another name that doesn't ... you'll see in a second ...)

```r
fun((quux = 1+2))
# len(Args) : 1 
# len(Names): 0 
# Names     :
```

In your use of `mutate`, that function generally requires that all of its arguments are named<sup>1</sup>. (In fact, all function calls will be affected this way, not just in `dplyr`.)

Now, look in your environment and see that `quux` now exists with the value of `3`. This is because R starts evaluating `fun`, and when its arguments are used (in my `dots <- list(...)`), R then evaluates the `...` expressions. (It chooses to not evaluate from the inside-out in order to support "lazy" evaluation ... too much for this answer, perhaps.) Now that we're "inside" `fun` and want to evaluate the `...`-expressions, it sees as its first (sole) argument the expression `(quux = 1+2)`, which is evaluated in the calling context (which is why `quux` is called in the call_ing_ environment instead of within the function). When that expression is evaluated, the side-effects of it are that `quux` is created (or overwritten) in the calling environment and the value `3` is stored in it. Now, the value of the expression itself (which is just `3`, no names) is returned as the `...`-expressions.

---

P.S.

1. Technically, `mutate` and similar `dplyr` verbs can accept an unnamed expression, where the return value of that expression returns a `data.frame`-like object that already has names. For instance:

   ```r
   mtcars[1:3,1:4] %>%
     mutate(data.frame(mpg2 = mpg+2, cyl3 = cyl*3))
   #                mpg cyl disp  hp mpg2 cyl3
   # Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 23.0   18
   # Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 23.0   18
   # Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 24.8   12
   ```

   I think this is not often used much, at least not in questions on SO nor in most howtos/tutorials for teaching `dplyr` and data-science-y things. (For dplyr-devs, it would really be nice if this method could be extended to take any `list`-like object not just `data.frame`-objects. :-)